# Does svn:externals accept relative paths?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have SVN download automatically some projects from another part of the trunk to my current trunk location - i.e. sharing projects with SVN:Externals.

But I have it hard coded currently like so

```
   MS.Utils http://192.168.1.1/svn/repro/projects/TestProj/trunk/MainApp/src/MS.Utils
```

Now this is working and all is fine as I am currently in the TRUNK ... when I finish this project I will move it to a branch! hence the SVN:Externals will still be pointing to the trunk. Is is possible to put in Relative paths, so it will download from the trunk? When I move it to a branch or whatever it will download from that branch because of using relative paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html), you can specify relative urls in the svn:externals property as well.

> ../
>
> ```
> Relative to the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals
> ```
>
> property is set ^/
>
> ```
> Relative to the root of the repository in which the svn:externals
> ```
>
> property is versioned //
>
> ```
> Relative to the scheme of the URL of the directory on which the
> ```
>
> svn:externals property is set /
>
> ```
> Relative to the root URL of the server on which the svn:externals
> ```
>
> property is versioned

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but now it has presented me with an issue. let me explain. I am currently in my trunk and using the normal relative syntax (ie windows syntax) this is what should work, to give you an idea     MyCompany.Utils ..\..\MyCompany.SubApplication/src/MyCompany.Utils          but of course it doesn't work with multiple ..\..\ for example... If i use any of the others it would take me further back away from TRUNK.

Comment: The idea is that the externals work whether in a branch, tag or trunk... there are 2 application directories within Trunk....  i need to link from 1 to another using externals....  i currently have the FULL path including Trunk hardcoded....